# How to get tag of an imageview in a stackview

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, ios11, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have a horizontal uistackview and i have 5 imageviews in it. I need to get id of the imageview that is tapped. I tried adding tap gesture identifier and get sender's id, but i am not getting it.

What i have tried till now is as follows

```
@IBOutlet weak var userRateViewStar1ImageOutlet         : UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var userRateViewStar2ImageOutlet         : UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var userRateViewStar3ImageOutlet         : UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var userRateViewStar4ImageOutlet         : UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var userRateViewStar5ImageOutlet         : UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var userRateViewTextAreaOutlet           : UITextView!

@IBOutlet var starOutletCollectionOutlet                : [UIImageView]!


 @IBAction func starRatingAction(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer)
{
    var tag = sender.view!.tag

    print(tag)

}
```

Basically i am trying to implement rate feature.

So can someone suggest me a way to implement this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: the UITapGestureRecognizer on which view(s) is attached ?

Comment: @AndreaMugnaini Its attached to the 5 image views

Comment: what is printing print(tag) ?

Comment: I am trying to print the the senders tag. I have assigned tag to 5 image views

Answer (score 0):

An easier way might be to create an IBOutletCollection e.g:

```
 //1. Create An Array Of Your ImageViews
 @IBOutlet var ratingStarImageViews: [UIImageView]!
```

Then assign a tag and the gesture to them e.g:

```
 //2. Assign Tags To The Them

    var tag = 0

    for view in ratingStarImageViews{

        let ratingGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:  #selector(starRatingAction(_:)))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(ratingGesture)
        view.tag = tag
        tag += 1
    }
```

Hope it helps.